# Chord diagram with D3 js showing only it's bottom right quarter

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to create a chord diagram using d3 js in a React js project. The problem that i encounter is that the display of my chart works partially, as it shows only the bottom right side (only one quarter) of the chart. here is an example of the chart: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-leaf-3lgjwc , and here is the code of my chart component:

```
const ChordDiagram = ({ data }) => {
  const mySVGRef = useRef(null);
  const wrapperRef = useRef();

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = { top: 10, right: 30, bottom: 30, left: 40 },
    width = 400 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 400 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  useEffect(() => {
    var svg = d3.select(mySVGRef.current);

    //so that we dont have duplication
    svg.html(null);
    svg
      .attr("width", width)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .attr("transform", `translate(${margin.top * 12},${margin.top * 12})`);

    // give this matrix to d3.chord(): it will calculates all the info we need to draw arc and ribbon

    const res = d3
      .chord()
      .padAngle(0.05) // padding between entities (black arc)
      .sortSubgroups(d3.descending)(data);

    // add the groups on the inner part of the circle
    svg
      .datum(res)
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("g")
      .data((d) => d.groups)
      .join("g")
      .append("path")
      .style("fill", "grey")
      .style("stroke", "black")
      .attr("d", d3.arc().innerRadius(200).outerRadius(210));

    // Add the links between groups
    svg
      .datum(res)
      .append("g")
      .selectAll("path")
      .data((d) => d)
      .join("path")
      .attr("d", d3.ribbon().radius(200))
      .style("fill", "#69b3a2")
      .style("stroke", "black");
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-lg-1"></div>
      <div className="col-lg-10 chart-div" ref={wrapperRef}>
        <svg ref={mySVGRef}></svg>
      </div>
      <div className="col-lg-1"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChordDiagram;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you should fix:

1. No need to set transform for `<svg>`. Remove:

```
svg.attr("transform", `translate(${margin.top * 12},${margin.top * 12})`);
```

2. No need to set `svg` datum (in both occasions).
3. Create a `<g>` element under `svg` and cet its origin to the center of svg:

```
const container = svg.append('g')
  .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left + width/2},${margin.top + height/2})`);
```

, then append all your elements (groups and links) under `container`